# Running Macro disables formula entry

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, macros

Run a Macro on an Excel 2007 workbook, now formulas no longer work in the modified workbook? I can type a simple (like "=5") in a blank cell and hit enter and what I typed is shown, not the result of the formula. Same for complex formulas ("=vlookup(..."). How do I fix?

Comment: I don't think it's related to the macros.  What is the number format of the cells?  Can you post some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you accidentally turned on the "Show Formulas" option. You can disable it by going to the Formulas tab→Formula Auditing→Show Formulas. Alternately, the hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> (that's the tilde key at the top left of your keyboard).